# Extra argument 'data' in call Firebase swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uitableview, dictionary

Need some help regarding the firebase dict error. Already tried some solutions related to the question but didn't worked..
i want to fetch and update data using an alertview into the table,but i am having an error regarding the dict as **Extra argument 'data' in call** in the **addtaskpop()** function in submit action marked below

**Secondviewcontroller.swift**

```
    func addtaskpop() {
        let db = Firestore.firestore()

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Task", message: "Enter your Task and Amount", preferredStyle: .alert)

        let submit = UIAlertAction(title: "Enter", style: .default)
        {
            (_) in

             let task1 = alertController.textFields?[0].text
             let amount1 = alertController.textFields?[1].text
            let income1 = alertController.textFields?[2].text


            self.dev = income1!
            print("dev is \(self.dev)")
          let amountcolor = Int(amount1!)
            self.income.isHidden = false
//            let incomeint = Int(income1!)
//            var incometotal = incomeint
//            incometotal = (incomeint + incomeint)
            self.income.text = ("Income is Rs. \(self.dev)")
            self.amount.append(amount1!)
            let text = amount1
            let textInt = Int(text!)
            self.numbers.append(textInt!)

            let total = self.numbers.reduce(0, +)
            let amountstring = String(total)
            self.totalamount.text = ("Rs.\(amountstring)")



            let date = Date()
            let format = DateFormatter()
            format.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"
            let formattedDate = format.string(from: date)
            print(formattedDate)


            self.poptaskarray.append(task1!)
            self.date.append(formattedDate)
            self.mytableView.reloadData()


            var docRef: DocumentReference? = nil
            docRef = db.collection("Tasks").addDocument(data: [ **Extra argument 'data' in call**
                "expensename": task1.text ?? "empty task",
//                "expensename": task1.text ?? "empty task",
                "minus": amount1.text ?? "empty task",
                "date": "\(formattedDate!)",
                "amount": self.totalamount.text ?? "empty task",
                "income": income.text ?? "empty task",


            ]) { err in
                if let err = err {
                    print("Error adding document: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                } else {
                    print("Document added with ID: \(docRef!.documentID)")
                }
            }
        }

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .destructive) { (_) in

        }
        alertController.addTextField { (textField) in
            textField.placeholder = "Enter your task"
        }
        alertController.addTextField { (textField) in
            textField.placeholder = "Enter your amount"
            textField.keyboardType = .numberPad
//            textField.text = "Rs. "


        }
        alertController.addTextField { (textField) in
            textField.placeholder = "Enter your income"
            textField.keyboardType = .numberPad        
        }    

        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
        alertController.addAction(submit)
        //finally presenting the dialog box
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }   
}
```

I have Created a **Task.swift**

```
import Foundation

struct Task{
    var expensename:String
    var done: Bool
    var date: String
    var id: String
    var amount: String
    var income: String
    var minus: String
    var dictionary: [String: Any] {
        return [
            "expensename": expensename,
            "done": done,
            "date": date,
            "amount": amount,
            "income": income,
            "minus": minus
        ]
    }
}

extension Task{
    init?(dictionary: [String : Any], id: String) {
        guard
        let expensename = dictionary["expensename"] as? String,
        let done = dictionary["done"] as? Bool,
        let date = dictionary["date"] as? String,
        let amount = dictionary["amount"] as? String,
        let income = dictionary["income"] as? String,
        let minus = dictionary["minus"] as? String
            else {
                return nil

        }

        self.init(expensename: expensename, done: done, date: date, id: id, amount: amount , income: income, minus: minus)
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated!!

Thanks and Regards

Comment: I think you are adding a lot of unrelated code to the issue, could you make it simpler?

Comment: i did ! please look at the code @ahmad f

Comment: In your first code snippet, try to remove an enclosing curly brace `}`, will it work?

Comment: ummm!! NOPEEEE!!

Comment: I copy and pasted the Firestore section of code in a project, starting with `var docRef:` and changed the var assignments like from this `"expensename": task1.text ?? "empty task",` to this `expensename: "some expense"`, and lastly fixed this `error.localizedDescription` and ran the code. Worked perfectly with no errors.

Comment: @jay ```fatalError("Unable to initialize type \(Task.self) with dictionary \(document.data())")``` also the data is not getting inserted into firebase

Comment: That error has nothing to do with Firebase or the question. You asked about *Extra argument 'data' in call Firebase swift* which we cannot duplicate. Your comment is stating your cannot initialize the Task object with document.data() - the two issues are unrelated based on the code in the question. However, there is no code in the question that initializes a task object and it's unclear where that error is occurring. It's best to keep questions limited to one question so we can focus on that answer. Can you update and clarify your question?